# Tinymce, textarea in my textarea editor

Tags: tinymce, textarea

I use TinyMCE.

If I insert in my textarea (editor) another texarea, tinymce considers that the closing tag of this one is concerned and so he closes the editor. All code can be found there after outside the editor ...

Have you any idea?

Below code works :

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1">
    <input type="text" value="okokokok"/>
</textarea>
```

Below code don't works :

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1">
    <textarea>Blablablabla</textarea>
    <input type="text" value="okokokok"/>
</textarea>
```

Here, `"<input type="text" value="okokokok"/></textarea>"` will be found outside editor...

Do you understand my problem ?

Comment: this works, see my fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Opcaab

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the ID attributes of "textarea" elements.
This will fix appearing a textarea inside the editor.

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem, rather then remove the id attr give them a id value, do not use "id" less textarea. it works in tinymce 4.

a  `<textarea id="try">textarea in </textarea>` out of the textarea